# How do I free string (C)?

Tags: c, free, c-strings

So basically I declared a new string that I want to assign a number to with number and when I push it onto a stack I want to free the string to give it another number ...etc.
Here is the code :

```
typedef struct skval skval;
struct skval
{
    int val;
    skval * pre;
};

char * chcpy(char * str, char chr)
{
    int len = strlen(str);

    str[len++] = chr;
    str = (char *)realloc(str, (len + 1));
    str[len] = '\0';
    len++;

    return str;
}
```

```
char * exp;

skval * vls = createStackVal();
char * svl = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
int i = 0;

*svl = '\0';

while (exp[i] != '\0')
{
    if (isdigit(exp[i]))
    {
        while (exp[i] != ' ' && exp[i] != '\0')
        {
            svl = chcpy(svl, exp[i]);

            i++;
        }

        vls = push_val(vls, atoi(svl));

        /// free(svl); ...
    }

    i++;
}

printStackVal(vls);
```

If there is another way to tackle things I would like to know. Because I know for sure that this is not an efficient way of doing it...

Comment: Allocate a large chunk.  Keep track of the capacity.  Only realloc when needed.

Comment: calling `strlen()` in `chcpy()` is a bad idea. Results in `O(N^2)`. Pass length as an argument to `chcpy()`.

Comment: Actually I think I found a solution. All I did was create a new string each time through the loop... But I don't know if it's any effictient. It works nonetheless. Is there a better way?

Comment: @PhoenXHO Just keep track of the length, and the allocated size. Only realloc when needed. A common technique is to simply double the size when needed. Then free it all at once when you're done.

Comment: @EmanuelP how do I free it?

Comment: @tstanisl is there an alternative?

Comment: @PhoenXHO With `free`... I'm sorry, what exactly do you not understand?

Comment: @EmanuelP I guess ```free()``` doesn't work on strings, it just crashes the program.

Comment: @PhoenXHO You should only call `free()` once, no matter how often you call `realloc()`. As said, keep track of the length of the string, and the allocated size. When they match, you call realloc and increase the size. When you want to reuse the string, set the length and position to 0. Then call `free()` when you're completely done and no longer need the string.

Comment: @EmanuelP I see, I get it. Yeah that might do.